# Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error from SQL Server on SSMS 17 while running a giant query:

> Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******

I have never seen this with ****'s before, and google searching seems to come up with nothing. Is there a known cause for why SQL Server would provide this message with asterisks?

Comment: Yes, implicit conversion. Probably you compare different data types and you have data that cannot be converted.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda but the op is literally receiving the error message with asterisks, that's the question

Comment: @Lamak Then it is really strange. Maybe column encryption/data masking is enabled.

Comment: is the error in SSMS or somewhere else?

Comment: @Kyle Which version do you use?

Comment: Sounds like server-level behavior.   Try asking on dba.

Comment: Column encryption and data masking are both off. This is SQL Server 2017 and I'm using SSMS 17. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've just got the same error from an Azure SQL database, and haven't managed to replicate it yet.

Comment: @johnathan I never figured out why the error had asterisks, I did figure out an error but I forget what it was. It was not at all relevant to the message.

Answer (score 4):

Are you getting data from a view? If so, you might be having issues with the view you're using. For example, in my case, I was pulling from a view and when I tried to view it in SSMS it showed me more details about what the error was.

Answer (score 3):

My error was also: Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.

My issue ended up being in my join, which was joining a varchar(50) field on an int field.

```
SELECT TOP (10) Product.Name, ProductDetails.Price
FROM Product
--the ProductDetails.Product field is a varchar field that contains 
--a string of the ProductID which is an int in the Product table
FULL JOIN Product.ProductID = ProductDetails.Product
```

I corrected this by casting the int field to a varchar

```
FULL JOIN CAST(Product.ProductID as varchar(50)) = ProductDetails.Product
```

P.S. I went back and later changed to a Left outer join which made more since for our business logic.
Also I did not test this code, it is modified for illustration purposes.

Details on reproducing:
Sometimes the query would work fine. I found I personally had issues when I had TWO string comparisons in my WHERE clause e.g.

```
WHERE field like '%' + @var + '%'
OR field2 like '%' + @var2 + '%'
```

If I had just one comparison, it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The asterisks appear when you do not have enough permissions. It seems they appear only in some scenarios (in my case, when using user-defined functions).

I don't know why, but it seems that if you GRANT UNMASK, you will see the real values.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to combine an nvarchar and int into a single string. Usually it tells me the data type where I screwed up but occasionally its the error you got.

I went from

```
SELECT ';' + [myNumber]
```

to

```
SELECT ';' + CAST([myNumber] as nvarchar(100))
```

which solved it for me.

So as the others have suggested, I guess it is something similar and you need to CAST or CONVERT one of your values to match the rest.

Comment: This is the solution for my case too!

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was that in the **time** parameter,  someone use -1 for nulls value.

so when  I wrote

```
where  TripStartTime   = -1
```

i got the error massage

> Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type *****

to solve it i add ''

```
where  TripStartTime   ='-1'
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the error was caused by an unusual value being introduced to a column I was using in a case statement. Adding a clause to the statement to cater for the new value resolved the issue.

If you can't spot where the problem is you need to run any sub-queries in isolation to see if they run (my statement was in a sub-query) and then start commenting out joins/selected columns until the query runs and you've pinpointed the issue.