# Azure SQL - failed converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, azure-sql-database

I'm facing the below error in Azure SQL Database when I'm trying to update a value within a table:

> Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.

I did some research and found out another person had the same issue and post the problem (source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089952/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-value-to-data-type)) - but somehow it was related to masked columns which is not my case.

In my case, I'm trying to update a `nvarchar` column (to be specific - `Code`) with a value of the same data type but I'm getting this wonderful error. My data table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ESFIZStepWF](
    [Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AlternativeDescription] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Inactive] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeSeries] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StepCode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CountryID] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [WEB] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [fStepStateWFCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ESFIZStepWF] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Code] ASC,
    [CountryID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Update statement**

```
        UPDATE ESFIZStepWF 
        SET Code=366
        WHERE Code=314
        AND CountryID='BG'
```

Had anyone else faced this issue in Azure SQL? Thanks

Comment: An `UPDATE` trigger is a possible explanation. What is the data type in the `to data type ******` part of the error message?

Comment: @Zhorov They literally mean the data types and values are masked out with asterisks. Good point regarding triggers though!

Comment: @cdrr, is the error solved now? Did you get any progresses?

Comment: @Zhorov - it wasn't about any update trigger. And the target data type was a `nvarchar(20)`.

Comment: @LeonYue - I solved by rewriting that piece of dynamic SQL by adding single quotes to the value. In any case, I don't know why this worked considering that the same previous piece of code had worked two weeks ago, on the same DB. Weird.

Comment: @cdrrr We may can't find the root cause of the issue. But congratulations you resolved it at all. It should be posted as an answer. May I help you do that?

Comment: What "piece of dynamic SQL"? There is none shown in the question... It seems incomplete.

Comment: @underscore_d - the update statement is part of dynamic SQL code. How is it different?

Comment: @cdrrr I said it's not clear, not that it's different. Where did you add quotes? around the `366` and `314`? It would help other readers to post an answer showing what you changed exactly :-)

Comment: @underscore_d - Yes, around `366` and `314`. Sorry for any misunderstanding :).

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations that the error is resolved now:

- "I solved by rewriting that piece of dynamic SQL by adding single
  quotes to the value."

Sometimes we may could not find the root cause, but we're glad that it's solved in the end.

I post it and this can be beneficial to other community members. If anyone could give more assists, we still very appreciate for you.

Comment: OP has clarified that the real update was to put quotes around the new/old values of `Code`.